# how to use javascript onClick function to change the logo?

Tags: javascript, frontend

hello guys hope you're doing well , im new to front-end and specifically javascript , so im working on a design to train myself , i added a button that onClick changes the menu style , and it worked but i tried changing the logo img src and it didn't work, it changes the img after two clicks and the image used before the click does not appear again when the button unclicked

```js
<script>
  let sidebar = document.querySelector(".sidebar");
  let sidebarBtn = document.querySelector(".sidebarBtn");
  sidebarBtn.onclick = function () {
    sidebar.classList.toggle("active");
    if (sidebar.classList.contains("active")) {
      sidebarBtn.classList.replace("bx-menu", "bx-menu-alt-right");
      document.getElementById("img").src = "mdn-logo.png";
    } else {
        sidebarBtn.classList.replace("bx-menu-alt-right", "bx-menu");
    }
  };
</script>
```

Comment: there is no such a thing as an "unclick" on an `onclick` event. You can put the previous image back when you click at it again, that you can do

Comment: please share your full code in a snippet here including HTML and CSS. I had this when I did my portfolio and I know how to do it. it's simple. just share your full code and I will edit it for you.

Comment: thanks guys, i edited the code and removed the onclick event. i'll keep the question if it can help others

Answer (score 1):

I think you're probably looking for the `mouseup` event, if that's what you mean by "unclick".

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/mouseup_event

Also, please refrain from using `Element.onclick` as it's quite outdated and deprecated. Instead, learn to use `Element.addEventListener`. You have more options and it's easier to manage as well. Read more on [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener).